# Persistance of data in NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have a bunch of nested `NSURLSessionDataTask`s and the data downloaded persists on calls of the method. I think it might have something to do with how NSURLSession handles cache??

Is there some way I can flush the cache so I get the most recent data when I call the method (thats supposed to refresh the data)

[Here's](https://github.com/AndrewSB/MistarApp/blob/master/mistar-with-storyboard/mistar-with-storyboard/MAViewController.m#L583) the code I'm working with if it helps at all...

--EDIT--

And a more readable excerpt of just one of the requests that I want to flush the cache from after use:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *homeRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/Login"]]];
[homeRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];
[homeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pin=%@&Password=%@",
                        [self percentEscapeString:pin],
                        [self percentEscapeString:password]];
NSData * postBody = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[homeRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];


NSURLSessionDataTask *homeTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:homeRequest
```

`homeTask` is the `NSURLDataTask` that I add to the `defaultSession`. I want to remove the cache it saves so that when I call the method that contains these lines again, it fetches from the server instead of the local cache.

Comment: There's an awful lot of code on that github page. Is this the post or the get? Why don't you quote here the _relevant_ code?

Comment: I notice that you create a mutable url request `setStudentIDRequest` but you never set its cache policy. If you are concerned about caching, you should do so.

Comment: I'm sorry @matt, I've edited the question

Comment: Cool, thanks - nice edit. I guess I don't see why NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData isn't doing what you're after here. Is the server responding to the POST request correctly?

Comment: I don't really have access to the server, but it responds to the POST request if I quit and reopen the app, so I'm pretty sure it's something like the NSURLSession either keeping a connection open to the server or just reloading from cache (which, yea, is really weird)

Comment: Do you have any guidance to try and fix this? I just verified it wasn't a disk r/w problem with concurrency or something... It's definitely fetching the same information from the server.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23679755/341994

Comment: Tried putting it in, didn't change anything.

Comment: Just realized that the *first* time I login each time I run the app, it gives me a cookie... The "Set Cookie" key on the left sublime http://i.imgur.com/PFN4TjC.png
Could that be the problem? I only get the cookie the first time I run the method each time I run the app? The cookie would return the same data no matter what. So maybe I'm not deleting the cookie?

Comment: Try setting the configuration's `HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy` to `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever`.

Answer (score 0):

Is `defautSession` a local variable pointing to `[NSURLSession sharedSession]`?  I would try using an ephemeral session instead.  It is almost the same except that it doesn't cache data to disk.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config =
    [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
```

If that still doesn't fix the problem, then invalidate it before posting again.  Use

```
[defaultSession invalidateAndCancel]
```

after your task has completed and then create a new session before the next time you need to post.