# Always getting back cached data in NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I'm facing a very strange issue when using `NSURLSessionDataTask` to post a JSON request to the server.

The first request goes through and I receive the correct JSON response, when I do a second request I'm getting always back the old response and the server never receives the request. Even if I turn on airplane mode the `NSURLSessionDataTask` does work an I get back the old response again.

That's the code I'm using:

```
- (void)getJSONFromURL:(NSURL*)url identifierCode:(NSInteger)code
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request addValue:[DataController sharedInstance].currentUser.userToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Token"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

if (![SVProgressHUD isVisible])
    [SVProgressHUD show];

NSURLSessionDataTask *postTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    [self handleResponse:httpResponse withJSON:json identifierCode:code];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    });
}];

[postTask resume];
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the issue, I don't know why this has changed, because I never had to set that property before. Anyway I set `configuration.URLCache = NULL;` and now everthing works fine again.

Comment: arggh. This got me too.

The default session configuration uses a persistent disk-based cache (except when the result is downloaded to a file) and stores credentials in the user’s keychain. It also stores cookies (by default) in the same shared cookie store as the NSURLConnection and NSURLDownload classes.

Answer (score 1):

you can set

```
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
```

to disable it per request